# Adding submodules to a repository

Tags: git, git-submodules

I added another repository as a submodule on my repository `(/path/myrepo)` on git.I am using git extensions on Windows. After adding the repository the only file that I committed is

```
[submodule "comms"]
    path = comms
    url = http://xxx-eng1/stash/scm/ta/sub.git
```

The repository is there in my `/path/myrepo`. Should I commit and push this submodule into my master?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should. The `.gitmodules` file is version-controlled with the other files, like the `.gitignore` file. It’s also pushed and pulled with the rest of the project.

you can do `$ git diff --cached --submodule` to be more clear

when you commit these changes you will see message like 
`create mode 160000 comms`

The 160000 mode is a special mode in Git which means you’re recording a commit as a directory entry rather than a subdirectory or a file